# Moving the labels under the unit circle

Tags: tikz-pgf

The labels -1 and 1 in the following (TikZ)-code are under the line of the unit circle:

```
\draw (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0);
\draw (1,0) arc(0:360:1);
\foreach \i [count=\j] in {-1,1}
{\draw (\i,0) coordinate (x\j) edge ++(0,2pt) -- ++(0,-2pt) node [below=5pt, anchor=mid, font=\scriptsize] {\i};}
```

How can I correct that?
Thank you!

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: add some conditional anchor

    `anchor=90+\i*45`

instead of `anchor=mid`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little simplified:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[font=\scriptsize]
    (-1.5, 0) -- (1.5, 0)
    (0, 0) circle[radius=1]
    (-1, 0) node[below left] {$-1$}
    (1, 0) node[below right] {$1$}
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]